# Are custom repository instances created per request?

Tags: mikro-orm

I am trying to create an application with mikro-orm and apollo-server-express, I want to use the batch processing and the caching of the Facebook dataloader.

Normally, Facebook dataloader instances are creates per request. If mikro-orm also creates custom repository instances per request and if all calls to `EntityManager.getRepository()` in the same request gets the same instance, it may be the perfect place to create the dataloader instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repositories are created as singletons, so only one instance exists per `EntityManager` instance. You should fork this EM to have one instance per request, either manually, or via `RequestContext` middleware:

https://b4nan.github.io/mikro-orm/identity-map/

This way, each request will have its own `EntityManager`, that will have its own cache of repository instances.

Keep in mind that if you use `RequestContext`, you should get the request specific `EntityManager` from it, and get the repository from there:

```
// beware that this will return null if the context is not yet started
const em = RequestContext.getEntityManager();

// gets request specific repository instance
const repo = em.getRepository(Book);
```